# Laravel unisharp file manager editor not found

Tags: php, laravel, file-manager

When i'm clicking on a file/image in the filemanager it opens the function `useFile()`. THe functies tries to find an editor.

Anyone knows how to implement the editor? The documentation is only good for installing the manager.
[image]

Comment: hi, i have the same problem. did you solve it?

Comment: @heavymetal91 nope, just commented it out. I dont have an editor but i can open word, excel pdf enz... using the microsoft plugin